# After Win10 Anniversary update, only one account at a time on the updated PC can access NAS shares

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, nas

Help! As the title says, I have a laptop (an old Dell Studio 15) running the Win 10 Anniversary update and after hours of having trouble connecting to network shares on my very reliable QNAP TS-269 Pro, I discovered a repeatable problem: only one user account on the Dell at a time can connect to the shared drives. However, it's not a NAS problem since I have another pre-Anniversary Win10 PC that doesn't have this issue.

For instance, I have two accounts on the Dell named SysAdmin and Bill, and I occasionally switch between them. If I log on as Bill first, Bill can connect to the shares but if I switch accounts (without logging off), SysAdmin cannot access the drives and vice versa. If Bill logs off, SysAdmin can now connect to the shares but if Bill logs back on, he's lost access until SysAdmin logs off.

The problem shows itself as soon as the second user logs in--an error message pops up saying "Could not reconnect all network drives". After the message disappears, if I open Windows Explorer, all my network locations are listed but they have a red cross on their icons. If I try to connect to one of them, e.g. BillDocs, by double clicking on its icon, I get a "Restoring Network Connections" error with the text "An error occurred while reconnecting R: to \NASName\BillDocs Microsoft Windows Network: The parameter is incorrect. The connection has not been restored."

I did add the IP address and the NAS name to the Windows Hosts file, and I can ping the NAS using its name from the account without share access (so the name does get resolved to the correct IP address). I've reset DNS caches, rebooted many times, etc. but the problem persists and I'm not great at networking so it's very frustrating--although I'm very grateful the problem is repeatable!

And as I said above, I have another Win10 computer without the Anniversary update and it doesn't have this problem. So, is it possible this is a bug in the Anniversary update? Or is there some way to further diagnose the problem as I may have buggered up some Windows file sharing or networking options when I first had trouble? E.g. I recreated WinSock and WinSocks entries in the registry but that's the only thing I've touched in there, and I haven't touched the NAS at all.

Thanks for any suggestions!
Audios